# Audio cd doesn't play

Tags: mount, audio, audio-cd

I'm trying to play an audio CD in Debian but each time I insert the CD, while there appears an icon with the CD in the screen, when I try opening it I get the message:

```
Failed to mount "Audio CD". Location is not mountable.
```

I've been searching since yesterday but as I see there is a general problem with audio CDs because the system cannot mount them (they are iso data?)
So, is there a way to fix this problem?

Note: I have found suggestions of using *cdparanoia* or *soundjuicer*. Should these programs solve the problem(if truly there is one)?

Note2:

I have tried these:

```
   root@debian:/home/kwstas# mkdir /mnt/cd && mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cd
   mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
   mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.



   root@debian:/home/kwstas# mkdir /mnt/cd && sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cd
   mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/cd’: File exists


   root@debian:/home/kwstas# mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cd
   mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
   mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.`
```

Comment: Why would you want to 'mount' audio cd? Usually you just play it with `mplayer -cache 5000 cdda://1` where 1 is your track no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use these commands in the terminal:

```
mkdir /mnt/cd && mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cd
```

Else try this in the terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/cd && sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cd
```

Or, if mkdir works:

```
mkdir /mnt/cd && sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cd
```

Or, if the directory has already been created:

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cd
```

Edit: I've googled and found this
[link](http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?20727-cdrom-input-output-error).

It's about mounting an audio CD. It reads you can't mount them because of no filesystem. You need another program indeed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have tried your suggestions. I will make an edit to my post to show you the results. It didn't work.

Comment: Try dmesg | tail or so

Comment: I got:

root@debian:/home/kwstas# dmesg | tail
[   79.736723] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[   79.736728] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   79.736731] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[   79.736733] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[   79.736736] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[   79.736740] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[   79.736743] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[   79.736744] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[   79.736751] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[   79.736769] EXT4-fs (sr0): unable to read superblock

Comment: It looks like the cd is broken

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The cd has an i/o error which means the first bytes are broken

Comment: I don't know CedianO. From search I've made, there are others to that had problems with playing audio cd's. Anyway, I will try some other cd and see what happens. Note that I got suggestions of using sound-juicer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 4):

You don't mount Audio CDs. You can read about it here [Mount CD ROM in Linux](http://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-cdrom-in-linux) at 4. Mounting Audio CD chapter.

> In order to listen to a music CD all what needs to be done is to insert music CD ( Compact Dics ) into CD-ROM/DVD-ROM drive and fire up you favorite music CD player.

In order to listen to Audio CD you can refer to this article [Mplayer: Play Audio CD](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-mplayer-playing-audio-dvd-cd-using-bash-shell/). What you need to do is simply use a command below:

`mplayer -cdrom-device /dev/cdrom -cache 5000 cdda://1`

where `1` is your track number, and `-cache 5000` option indicates that mplayer should cache 5 seconds of audio to avoid delays when CD stops (when you use Pause).

Comment: Thanks for the reply here. I now know- you are correct. I will install a music player.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see an audio CD in your file system, assuming it is functioning and visible in your file explorer, look for it to have been auto-mounted at `/run/user/$(id -u)/gvfs/cdd*`.

In other words, you can play a CD from the command line with:

```
find /run/user/1000/gvfs/cdd* -iname "*.wav" -print0 |xargs -0 -n1 aplay
```

*Warning: This might suffer from underruns due to a lack of buffering.*